# Regex validation of a Colfusion property doesn't work with commas (,)

Tags: regex, coldfusion, escaping, coldfusion-9

I have this little component in ColdFusion 9:

```
component  
    displayname = "My Component"
    accessors = "true"
{
    property
        name = "myProperty"
        type = "string"
        validate = "regex"
        validateparams = "{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)' }";
}
```

which works as expected:

```
<cfscript>
    myComponentInstance = new myComponent();

    myComponentInstance.setMyProperty('Eats');
    // Property is correctly set

    myComponentInstance.setMyProperty('Shoots');
    // Property is correctly set

    myComponentInstance.setMyProperty('Drinks');
    // Error: The value does not match the regular expression pattern provided.
</cfscript>
```

But if I modify the validation regex to allow a value like with a comma (,) in it

```
validateparams = "{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats, Shoots & Leaves)' }"
```

then I get an error on the instance creation

```
<cfscript>
    myComponentInstance = new myComponent();
    /* Error while parsing the validateparam
       '{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats, Shoots & Leaves)' }'
       for property myProperty */
</cfscript>
```

**It seems like ColdFusion can't process a regular expression with a comma, nor have I found a way of escaping it.**

If I try to use a backslash (\), as a regex escaping character, it is then processed as a foreslash (/) by ColdFusion:

```
validateparams = "{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats\, Shoots & Leaves)' }"

<cfscript>
    myComponentInstance = new myComponent();
    /* Error while parsing the validateparam
       '{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats/, Shoots & Leaves)' }'
       for property myProperty */
</cfscript>
```

Other forms of escaping that I have tried, but to no avail, are:

```
validateparams = "{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats#chr(44)# Shoots & Leaves)' }"

validateparams = "{ pattern = '(Eats)|(Shoots)|(Leaves)|(Eats,, Shoots & Leaves)' }"
```

Comment: Is it definitely the comma, and not the ampersand (I realise this is an example, but still: it's unclear from said example that it's *definitely* the comma)? Either way, it *should* work. Can you post the *actual* regex?

Comment: I have definitely checked that ampersands, foreslashes, dots and other characters do work. My guess is that, since `validateparams` is a structure, ColdFusion thinks that the value of the key `pattern` ends right before the comma, thus throwing an error because it cannot parse the string into a structure.

Comment: I can confirm it does the same for me.  Sounds like a bug, I would log one w/ Adobe.  Its an odd syntax.  Its a "struct" but its in a string (defining the struct w/o the quotes throws an error as well).  Odd syntax choice by Adobe on this one.

Comment: Adam, a single ampersand is not a significant character in regex, and also if you specify an invalid regex you get a more specific error (e.g. `Unmatched [] in expression.` or whatever). The actual code they've provided does give the behaviour described (checked in CF10 u12), so unless there's a documented reason for not allowing commas, it does seems there's something buggy about the validateparams processing.

Comment: Xevi, you can use `\x2C` for the comma - that is the regex encoded version, so it bypasses whatever buggering about CF is doing.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBoughton, I know that. I was not suggesting the regex was off - clearly it's not a regex problem - I was just making sure that we are getting all the correct information. Which I think is pretty clear from my comment. FWIW, I can replicate on CF9 too. It's some stupidity in the way Adobe are choosing to parse that string.

Comment: @PeterBoughton, if I use `\x2C`, then CF does parse the struct, however I still can't set the property to the correct value: both `setMyProperty('Eats\x2C Shoots & Leaves')` and `setMyProperty('Eats, Shoots & Leaves')` return a *value does not match the regular expression pattern provided* error

Comment: Ah yeah, it's going to be because the backslash is being changed to `/` so it's not working. Without being able to use a backslash, you'll have to do `(?![+-])[+--]` where the `[+--]` is a range between `+` and `-` (the characters either side of comma), and the `(?![+-])` is a negative lookahead to prevent those two non-comma characters being accepted. (A less obscure but non-strict option would be to use either `.` to match any (non-newline) character, or `[[:punct:]]` to at least only match punctuation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in ColdFusion. Raise it as such: https://bugbase.adobe.com/. I can replicate it in CF 9.0.1. I'm working on a work-around... will get back to you if I come up with something.

NB: one can pare the repro `validateparams` string down to this: `{pattern = ","}`. I'm guessing Adobe are using the comma as a delim, and it never occurred to them it might be data (they're a bit like that with delimited strings).

Comment: Didn't see your follow-up comment, @PeterBoughton. Nice one!

Comment: I've just submitted a bug report: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3695003